# Probability on white and black.

Tags: probability

In a sock drawer, there are only identical black socks and identical white socks, a total of less than 50 socks together.
If someone withdraws two socks at random, the probability that he gets a pair of the same colour is 0.5. What is the largest number of black socks that can be in the drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $x$ white socks and $y$ black socks.  The order we take out socks doesn't matter, so there are ${x+y}\choose{2}$ ways of choosing two socks.
There are $xy$ ways of failing to choose a pair, and therefore $\frac{xy}{{x+y}\choose{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$.

The conditions of the problem demand that we find all pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x,y\in\mathbb{N}, x+y\leq50$, and $\frac{xy}{{x+y}\choose{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$, and then find the result that has the highest possible $y$.

$$\frac{xy}{{x+y}\choose{2}}=\frac{xy}{\frac{(x+y)(x+y-1)}{2}}=\frac{2xy}{(x+y)(x+y-1)}=\frac{2xy}{x^2+2xy+y^2-x-y}$$
$$\frac{2xy}{x^2+2xy+y^2-x-y}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$4xy=x^2+2xy+y^2-x-y$$
$$x+y=x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$$.

As such, we can conclude that all solutions $(x,y)$ have the property that their sum is equal to the square of their difference, and therefore the sum must be a perfect square less than or equal to 50.  Because x and y are both at least 1, their sum can be 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, or 49.

For $x+y=4$, we have that $|x-y|=2$, which gives the pairs $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$.

For $x+y=9$, we have that $|x-y|=3$, which gives the pairs $(3,6)$ and $(6,3)$.

For $x+y=16$, we have that $|x-y|=4$, which gives the pairs $(6,10)$ and $(10,6)$.

For $x+y=25$, we have that $|x-y|=5$, which gives the pairs $(10,15)$ and $(15,10)$.

For $x+y=36$, we have that $|x-y|=6$, which gives the pairs $(15,21)$ and $(21,15)$.

For $x+y=49$, we have that $|x-y|=7$, which gives the pairs $(21,28)$ and $(28,21)$.

(It is worth noting that there is a pattern here.  The solutions for $x+y=a^2, x-y=a$ are always $(T_a,T_{a-1})$ where the sequence $T_i$ is the sequence of triangle numbers: $1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, \dots$)

The solution that maximizes $y$ is the solution $(21,28)$.